# How to add xlsx file on git?

Tags: excel, git

i want to add my .xlsx extension file to my git repo. This excel is already on my repo, i added some rows to the file so i need to push to the repo. But add comment doesn't add my file.
But i can't see this file on staged files.

I tried following command;

```
git add data/file.xlsx
```

And i also tried;

```
git add -f data/file.xlsx
```

these commands does not gives any error.

But i can't see this file on staged files. If i duplicate this file, i can add that file on staged files.
How can i solve this problem? Force didn't worked.
Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `git status` command? What does `git add data/file.xlsx` command output? What is the content of the repo's .gitignore file?

Comment: I cant see this file on staged files,  this add command not gives an error there is no output.  igonored files only venv folder

Comment: the `git status` command what gives as output?

Comment: no changes added to commit

Comment: Are you really sure you changed and saved this file and not another somewhere else? Double check...